# Parse.com local storage: pinning objects removes all previous pinned objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com as backend for an iOS application. When I get all the remote objects from a relation and pin them, I can access them locally later.

However, I want to use the "updatedAt" property on a Parse object to only fetch updated objects remotely and update the local datastore.

How it is done:

```
        query.whereKey("updatedAt", greaterThan: lastDate)
        let results = try query.findObjects()
        try PFObject.pinAll(results)
```

Let's say I have 10 objects locally, and the remote query only returns 1 object. After pinning the one returned object, the other 10 local objects are removed. The result is that only the one new remote object is saved locally.

Is it possible to use the "updatedAt" key to only fetch new objects and still have all objects in the local database? How is this done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need not to pin the results as they are already pinned. Have you tried to remove try PFObject.pinAll(results) and try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! There should always be a Pin call to save the object locally. What I also tried is to only Pin an object when it is created remotely. The result is the same..